# Where is Poco ByteOrder::ToNetwork() defined?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I am trying to find Poco ByteOrder::ToNetwork() in the Poco source code and all I can find, after searching the entire source, is this:

```
    static Int16 toNetwork(Int16 value);
    static UInt16 toNetwork (UInt16 value);
    static Int32 toNetwork(Int32 value);
    static UInt32 toNetwork (UInt32 value);
#if defined(POCO_HAVE_INT64)
    static Int64 toNetwork(Int64 value);
    static UInt64 toNetwork (UInt64 value);
#endif
```

in ByteOrder.h

Where is the actual implementation? Can't find it on github either:

https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tonetwork

Answer (score 1):

Poco's endiness conversions are defined by the macros `POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG` and `POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_LIT` in ByteOrder.h.  On big endian systems those macros expand to `POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP` and `POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP` respectively and the opposite on little endian systems.

```
//
// some macro trickery to automate the method implementation
//
#define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, type) \
     inline type ByteOrder::op(type value)        \
     {                                                      \
          return value;                                \
     }
#define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, type) \
     inline type ByteOrder::op(type value)        \
     {                                                      \
          return flipBytes(value);                \
     }


#if defined(POCO_HAVE_INT64)
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP(op) \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, Int16)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, UInt16)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, Int32)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, UInt32)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, Int64)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, UInt64)
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP(op) \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, Int16)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, UInt16)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, Int32)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, UInt32)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, Int64)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, UInt64)
#else
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP(op) \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, Int16)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, UInt16)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, Int32)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP_(op, UInt32)
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP(op) \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, Int16)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, UInt16)   \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, Int32)    \
          POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP_(op, UInt32)
#endif


#if defined(POCO_ARCH_BIG_ENDIAN)
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_LIT POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP
#else
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_FLIP
     #define POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_LIT POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_NOOP
#endif


POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG(toBigEndian)
POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG(fromBigEndian)
POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG(toNetwork)
POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_BIG(fromNetwork)
POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_LIT(toLittleEndian)
POCO_IMPLEMENT_BYTEORDER_LIT(fromLittleEndian)
```